# Cannot rename file warning while using idempotent readlock in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Camel version 2.17.1 over a clustered environment with 2 nodes to process files. I use an idempotent readlock in my file consumer endpoint using a JDBCMessageIdRepository as the idempotent repository to stop multiple servers trying to process the same file.

Occasionally I see warnings in the SystemOut logs of one node saying a file could not be renamed while the other node processes the same file successfully.

Warning example:

```
[12/10/16 10:21:03:312 BST] 0000008f SystemOut     O 12 Oct 2016 10:21:03 [r-inboundCamelContext_Worker-1] FileConsumer      WARN  Endpoint[file://drop?delay=30000&idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:modified}-${file:size}&idempotentRepository=#filesInIdempotentRepository&move=done/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}-${file:name}&moveFailed=error/${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}-${file:name}&preMove=processing&readLock=idempotent&readLockRemoveOnCommit=true&runLoggingLevel=DEBUG&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=*+*+*+*+*+?] cannot begin processing file: GenericFile[drop\file-20161012_101320.xml] due to: Cannot rename file: GenericFile[drop\file-20161012_101320.xml] to: GenericFile[drop\processing\file-20161012_101320.xml]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot rename file: GenericFile[drop\file-20161012_101320.xml] to: GenericFile[drop\processing\file-20161012_101320.xml]]
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot rename file: GenericFile[drop\file-20161012_101320.xml] to: GenericFile[drop\processing\file-20161012_101320.xml]
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.renameFile(GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.java:115)
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy.begin(GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy.java:43)
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:367)
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:226)
                at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:190)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
                at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
                at org.apache.camel.pollconsumer.quartz2.QuartzScheduledPollConsumerJob.execute(QuartzScheduledPollConsumerJob.java:61)
                at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
                at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
stack
```

Is there a way to stop both nodes trying to process the same file?

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @user2768310: Any solution to this?

Comment: @Sian: Any solution to this?